# C++ pointer node help - copying a parameter into a linked list node changes a different section of that node

Tags: c++, linked-list

In a part of my code, I have a linked list that is set up like so:

```
struct msgNode {
    char * msg;
    char * timeStamp;
    msgNode * next;
};
```

There is a part of my code where I pass into a function `addMsg(char * msg, char * timeStamp)` and use `strcpy` to copy the content of each parameter into a new node and then add it to the end of the linked list (like so:)

```
void ChatRoom::addMsg(char * msg, char * timeStamp) {
    msgNew = new msgNode;
    strcpy(msgNew->msg, msg);
    //point A

    //what is this line doing to my code
    strcpy(msgNew->timeStamp, timeStamp);
    //point B

    msgNew->next = NULL;

    if (msgFirst == NULL) {
        msgFirst = msgNew;
        msgLast = msgNew;
    } else {
        msgLast->next = msgNew;
        msgLast = msgNew;
    }
}
```

My problem is that, while at point A `msgNew->msg` contains what `char * msg` contains, however at point B, `msgNew->msg` contains what `char * timeStamp` contains. For example if the parameter `char * msg` contained "testing" and the parameter `char * timeStamp` contained "2017-04-25 08:25:35", then at point A `msgNew->msg` contains "testing" and `msgNew->timeStamp` contains "2017-04-25 08:25:35", but at point B `msgNew->msg` contains "2017-04-25 08:25:35" and `msgNew->timeStamp` contains "2017-04-25 08:25:35". So the timeStamp is fine, but the msg seems to be overridden somehow?

Here's the link to the entire project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qeldl8gakbzowwx/AAC4zabNTOru9RkxLKGBy7Eua?dl=0

Comment: Given only those definitions, `strcpy(msgNew->msg, msg);` and `strcpy(msgNew->timeStamp, timeStamp); ` both invoke undefined behavior. Those members are indeterminate, and using them as *either* argument to `strcpy` is wrong.

Comment: Should I just use `=` for assigning them then?

Comment: You should use `std::string` that manages for you all allocation/deallocation of dynamic memory. If you really want to do it *by hand* (perhaps for practicing...) you **must** allocate some room for `msgNew.msg` and `msgNew->timeStamp` before using `strcpy`. Alternatively, you could use `strdup` that does it automagically. But you will then have to free that before freeing `msgNew` to avoid memory leaks. BTW that's the reason why `std::string` was invented...

Comment: Thank you so much both of you!! I tried both things (using `=` and allocating msgNew->msg and msgNew->timeStamp) and they both worked. I spent almost all day yesterday trying to figure out why this wasn't working so this was really helpful. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Despite you apparently solving the problem, I'll post here to point out why your original program is buggy.

Allocating a new `msgNode` will *not* allocate memory for `msg` and `timeStamp`. What is likely happening is that both `msg` and `timeStamp`, being uninitialized, is by chance pointing to the same (illegal) location, which is why you see `timeStamp` overwriting `msg`.

Proper intialization should be done as follows

```
void ChatRoom::addMsg(char * msg, char * timeStamp) {
    msgNew = new msgNode;

    msgNew->msg = new char[strlen(msg)];
    strcpy(msgNew->msg, msg);

    msgNew->timeStamp = new char[strlen(timeStamp)];
    strcpy(msgNew->timeStamp, timeStamp);

    //have to call delete[] for msg and timeStamp when finished

    //...
}
```